# Controlling Adruino through Python via pySerial

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino, ascii, pyserial

Hello and thank you in advance for your time,

I'm attempting to control a series of relays connected to my Arduino via a python script using pySerial and Tkinter. The problem is that, although I know my code is connecting to my Arduino (I hear the same flutter of relays that I get when I upload code using the Arduino software), I can't get the relays to respond to commands sent from my Tkinter GUI. Here is my python code:

```
ser = Serial(port=3, timeout=1, writeTimeout=1, baudrate=9600)  # ensure non-blocking

class Application(Frame):

    print("Arduino Dish Control Ready")

    def __init__(self, parent):  # create constructor
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)  # define parent
        self.parent = parent  # save reference of parent widget
        self.initUI()  # delegate creation of the initUI() method

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Dish Control")  # title of window

        Style().configure("TButton", padding=(0, 5, 0, 5), font='serif 10')

        self.columnconfigure(0, pad=4)
        self.columnconfigure(1, pad=4)
        self.columnconfigure(2, pad=4)
        self.columnconfigure(3, pad=4)
        self.columnconfigure(4, pad=4)

        self.rowconfigure(0, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(1, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(2, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(3, pad=3)

        def UP():  # define the UP command.
            ser.write(str(32))  # convert "32" to ASCII and send it via serial port (USB) to arduino.
            print ser.write(str(64))
            # sleep(0.1)
        up = Button(self, text="Up", command=UP)  # create button UP and set the command.
        up.grid(row=0, column=1)  # define position of UP button.


        self.pack()
```

And here is the relevant Arduino code:

```
void loop(){
  if(Serial.available() > 0){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    int inByte = Serial.read(); //read the incoming data
    Serial.print("I received: ");
    Serial.println(inByte, DEC);

    if(Serial.read() == 32){//If the serial reads 32...
      digitalWrite(8, LOW); //Motor Select Low
      digitalWrite(9, LOW);
      digitalWrite(10, LOW); //Motor 1 Low
      digitalWrite(11, LOW);
      digitalWrite(12, LOW); // Motor 2 Low
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      digitalWrite(6, HIGH); //Motor Power High
      digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
    }
  }
}
```

Sorry for include so much, but I'm uncertain as to where my error is.

EDIT:It has been requested that I include the traceback for the error given when I simply include ser.write(32) instead of ser.write(str(32)) in the python code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Radio Astro 4/PycharmProjects/untitled/DishControl.py", line 46, in UP
    ser.write(32)  # convert "1" to ASCII and send it via serial port (USB) to arduino.
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 283, in write
    data = to_bytes(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 75, in to_bytes
    for item in seq:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using "ser", the class instance instead of "Serial" in void_loop()  Not at all knowledgeable when it comes to serial ports, but "Serial" does not know which port to read/write, etc.

Comment: And should you have a ser.begin() in the python code.

Comment: I defined which port "Serial" is to use in the first line of the above code. Does defining it as "ser" void that information? If so, must I type the full line every time?
Also, where should I include ser.begin()? When looking up similar examples such as this one:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Interface-Python-and-Arduino-with-pySerial/step3/Program-Idle/
I don't see it used.

Comment: Okay I investigated your first suggestion, but I would still have to use something like this:
Serial.write(ser, 32), which works the same as ser.write(32) so long as "ser" is defined. I cannot omit "ser" from Serial.write(ser, 32) because an 'IronSerial' AND 'data' input are required here.

Answer (score 1):

The [Arduino documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/read) says about the `Serial.read()` command:

> #### Returns
>
> the first byte of incoming serial data available (or -1 if no data is available) - `int`

You are sending the *string* "32" to the micro controller, this actually is two bytes `[51, 50]` being sent. When checking `if(Serial.read() == 32)`, you check for the *byte value* 32, but the byte value 32 (ASCII space) is never being sent.

Change your send command to transmit the byte value directly:

```
ser.write(32)  # without str()
```

#### Edit:

[`Serial.write()`](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.write) takes a (byte-)string as argument, so you'll have to do the following:

```
ser.write(bytes([32]))  # convert the list `[32]` to a bytestring
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that doing that gives me an error:
"TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"
Is there another workaround for this that might work?

Comment: What exactly is your error and your traceback? Include this in your main question, please, the traceback is inevitable for solving your problem

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I was out of town for the weekend. I have updated the question to include the traceback.

Comment: @Matt: If this solved your problem, please tick the answer as "accepted"

Comment: It definitely helped but hasn't quite solved the problem. Once I get everything together I'll post a summary for anyone else that comes across this question and accept your answer!